# How to create a appendChild reagent element?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

For example:

```
    (defn place-background []
      [:div {:class "pbackground" 
             :style {:height (:fullheight @app-state)}}])

    (reagent/render-appendChild [place-background]
                          (. js/document (getElementById "container")))
```

because if I to use render-component it will replace the content

Answer (score 3):

```
(ns reagenttest.core
    (:require [reagent.core :as r]))


(defn sample-comp []
    [:div "hello there!"])

(defn appended-container [target]
    (let [id "some-unique-id"
          container (.getElementById js/document id)]

        (if container
            container
            (.appendChild target (doto (.createElement js/document "div")
                                     (-> (.setAttribute "id" id))))
            )))

(r/render [sample-comp] (appended-container (.getElementById js/document "app")))
```

Comment: But if I want duplicate ? 2 elements in my "app".. for example:

(draw {:width "200px :height "200px"})
(draw {:width "200px :height "200px"})